# stretch underbrace vertically word

Tags: ms-word, latex

use Microsoft Word to edit an equation with underbrace. The line is as follows:

\underbrace(ab+cdf-edf=9dc/ereat+asdfdgg-asfeefe-eafdgahty+atataeaattrat)

The problem is the symbol for underbrace is very flat, looking like a line with the downward pointing part too small to see. Is there a way to make it larger (e.g., is there a way to stretch the underbrace VERTICALLY)? The size of underbrace is set automatically in Latex and looks fine. But in Microsoft Word, the default just does not look especially when you have a long equation. I am not sure if there is a setting allowing you to change it. Many thanks! Gene

Comment: Already asked earlier at http://superuser.com/questions/783055/stretch-underbrace-vertically-or-make-the-pointing-part-of-underbrace-bigger-in

Comment: Is this a problem in MS Word, or in LaTeX?

Comment: Thanks! This is a problem in MS Word. Underbrace in latex looks fine and there is no need to adjust. But in MS Word, the downward pointing part of underbrace is very small and does not look professional. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My current solution is to draw a underbraket.